# Unit testing MediaElement in Windows 8 (C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-8, mediaelement

I've got a class with a MediaElement that I'm trying to write unit tests for, but I can't figure out how to unit test the parts that interact with the MediaElement. Specifically, I want to ensure that opening a file triggers the right code, and that my own class's state is updating along with the MediaElement's.

I'm using the ExecuteOnUIThread() trick mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/57815826-8cbb-4206-b2a6-3a3383dfe6ad) to create and work with the MediaElement, since I will get an RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD exception otherwise.

Then I use [this trick](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/12/27/easily-unit-testing-event-handlers/) to be able to test my own class's events, which connect to the MediaElement's own MediaOpened and CurrentStateChanged events.

However, I'm not seeing anything getting activated when I open an MP3 file from the internet, no matter how long I set the WaitOne to be. I've tried just bypassing my own class and testing MediaElement directly, but the events do not seem to fire at all.

Here is the test method I'm working with:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    await ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
    {
        var me = new MediaElement();
        bool opened = false;
        var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        me.MediaOpened += delegate
        {
            opened = true;
            mre.Set();
        };
        me.Source = new Uri("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52389/test-song.mp3");
        mre.WaitOne(5000);

        Assert.IsTrue(opened);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your commands, check CurrentState (Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.MediaElementState); that should reflect your actions. If you can't be sure if buffering has enough time and you don't want to wait for it, which is okay, then you can check for more than one. For example, here are the options:

```
Closed = 0
Opening = 1
Buffering = 2
Playing = 3
Paused = 4
Stopped = 5
```

After You call Play() you can check for (Opening | Buffering | Playing). See what I mean? At the same time you can check for what it should not be like !(Closed | Paused | Stopped). And so on. You probably can't check for the stream itself in a little ole unit test. But you should be able to check state.

Best of luck!

Comment: I'm having two issues with getting the testing to work. First of all, it doesn't like me trying to create a MediaElement in the unit test; I get an RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD exception. I'm using a trick mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/57815826-8cbb-4206-b2a6-3a3383dfe6ad) to work with UI elements, and then [this trick](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2007/12/27/easily-unit-testing-event-handlers/) to test event handlers. But I'm not seeing anything triggering the MediaOpened or PlayStateChanged events.